# Install Stanford CoreNLP using Maven dependency:get

Tags: java, maven, nlp

I'm trying to install Stanford CoreNLP (3.4.1) using Maven. 
Maven version is 3.3.3

I could download a jar file using `dependency:get` command like

```
$ mvn dependency:get  -DrepoUrl=http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-2014-08-27.zip -Dartifact=edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.4.1
```

We get `stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar` in `~/.m2/repository/edu/stanford/nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.4.1`
However, we do not get model files.
How can I get `stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar`?

I would like to know a command to get the model file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for downloading Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download), you can just add the two dependencies directly to your Maven POM like this:

```
<project>
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Is there some reason why you cannot do this?

Comment: Where should I write those lines? (I'm using Linux)  I want to install the package with some lines of commands.

Comment: You need to find your `pom.xml` file in your project.  Open that, make the changes as I have above, then refresh your Maven project.  The 2 dependencies you need will _magically_ appear in your `.m2` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I don't have project. Actually, I just want to run a command like `$ java -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref`, where classpass is added to the downloaded jar files.

Comment: Navigate to this page: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cedu.stanford.nlp and manually download the JARs you want.

Comment: I see. I got them! Last question: Is it possible to download all files (stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar, stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar, .... etc) with a single command?

Comment: Look into using `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`